# How to create html select option with data from MySql database with nodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, html-select

How can I add values to options on select menu from MySql db with nodeJS. Instead to hard-codded below.

```
<select id="select_id" multiple="multiple">
            <label for="one">
              <option value="test">test</option>
            </label>
            <label for="two">
              <option value="test2">test2</option>
            </label>
```

**UPDATE:**

It won't update the select menu but on `console.log(select)` give it me the select menu that I whant, but not in the html view

```
fetch('/data').then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>{

        var select = document.getElementById("chkveg");
        console.log(select);
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
                txt = document.createTextNode(data[i].username);
            option.appendChild(txt);
            option.setAttribute("value",data[i].username);
            select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
        }
    })
```

with code below works fine. Two code blocks give it me same result on `console.log(select)`

```
var select = document.getElementById("chkveg"),
      arr = ["html","css","java"];

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    var option = document.createElement("OPTION"),
        txt = document.createTextNode(arr[i]);
    option.appendChild(txt);
    option.setAttribute("value",arr[i]);
    select.insertBefore(option,select.lastChild);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I find that my jQuery function blocked adding the options in select menu.
has anyone have a idea how to solve that?

```
$(function() {
          $('#chkveg').multiselect({

              includeSelectAllOption: true

          });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an API with GET action to retrieve all of the data that you want to set as options. 
For example: In your backend file, define an api like this

```
app.get('/data',(req.res)=>{
  // connection holds the connection to the db
  connection.query('SELECT column_name from table_name',(err,result)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    else // result is the array of values in column_name
      res.send(result);
  })
});
```

Then in your client code you could do something like this:

```
fetch('\data').then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>{
\\ loop over the data and create markup
const markup = data.forEach(datum=>`<option>.....`)
document.querySelector("#select_id").appendChild(markup);
})
```

Comment: The first block is good and I have managed that, but i have problem with second block, don't give me results

Comment: Did you check if the API is giving back a response?

Comment: Yes API is giving response, I find that my jQuery function blocked adding the options in select menu.